# how to add trigger in mysql workbench, without UDF, using EER design

Tags: mysql, schema, trigger, mysql-workbench

I have designed a simple database using EER in workbench. However, i want to have a minimum value for the attribute salary (compared with min_value attribute from artist table). Here is the schema:
[image: ER]

and here is the equivalent in the EER mysql workbench:

[image: EER]

I need to check that the salary of each artist that acts on a movie, has a minimum value (lets say 1000), but how am i suppose to do that? I have checked in the options and all i see is:

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `Askisi_3db`$$
```

Should i use something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER min_salary
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF
salary, min_salary ON acts, artist
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.salary < min_salary)
BEGIN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20004, ‘Violation of Minimum Actor Salary’);
END;
.
run;
```

The problem is that the attribute is in a N-M relation and has to check keys in other tables. Salary matters only for artists that participate as actors in a movie and not for directors or writers. However not every artist must have a min_salary (may be null for some who participate as directors or writers). Is this feasible only via UDF fucntions or front end design? I would really like a simple and tidy solution :) 
**Please don't give suggestions about how the schema could be better, all i ask is on this particular design how to implement the check between salary and min_salary**

Comment: In proper DBMS you'd simply use a check constraint...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hmm you mean in acts table alone?

Comment: Yes, but as MySQL doesn't support check contraints, you need to find some workaround...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have edited the question. I forgot to say that the min_salary exists in artist and thats what i wanna compare to with salary.

Comment: You'll need two triggers (INSERT, UPDATE) on `acts` and two on `artists` for this. And I don't get the "N-M" thing. Artists and acts seem to have a 1-N relationship.

Comment: @ypercube it just means many to many relationship :) I dont know how to combine the attributes from different tables to do so. Any example would be welcomed :)

Comment: Oh, you mean that `acts` is the M-N relationship between `movies` and `artists`. OK.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger could be like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER 
    acts_INSERT_min_salary
BEFORE INSERT ON
    acts
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
        IF NEW.salary < 
            ( SELECT min_salary
              FROM artist
              WHERE artist_id = NEW.artist_artist_id
            )
        THEN 
            SET msg = 'Violation of Minimum Actor Salary.' ;
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = msg ;
        END IF ;
    END ;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You will need a similar trigger for the `UPDATE` operation on `acts` and another one for the `UPDATE` operation on `artist` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    artist_UPDATE_min_salary
BEFORE UPDATE ON
    artist
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
        IF NEW.min_salary >                             -- this part
            ( SELECT MIN(salary)                        -- is slightly
              FROM acts                                 -- different than
              WHERE artist_artist_id = NEW.artist_id    -- the other 
            )
        THEN 
            SET msg = 'Violation of Minimum Actor Salary.' ;
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = msg ;
        END IF ;
    END ;
```

Comment: Side note, why `prod_date` is a `VARCHAR` and not a `DATE`?

Comment: Thx for the code. Well i just forgot to add datetime thats all :p

Comment: why do i get an `ERROR: Error 1054: Unknown column 'artist_artist_id' in 'NEW'` i dont see anything wrong? :o

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE acts;` output in the question? The image shows it has an `artist_artist_id` column.

Comment: i think what i ask cannot be done with triggers. `ERROR: Error 1235: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'` :/

Comment: No, that error is because you are trying to create 2 triggers on the same table for the same action time (BEFORE) and same event (INSERT).

Comment: so should one of those lets say `INSERT` be `AFTER` for the same table?

Comment: No, I don't think you need AFTER triggers here, at all. You want an `BEFORE INSERT ON acts` (the 1st one above), an `BEFORE UPDATE ON acts` (code almost identical to the 1st one) and a `BEFORE UPDATE ON artist` (the 2nd in the answer). In total, just 3 triggers.

Comment: done that and i got those 2 errors, the 1st for the update on artist and the second error from the 2 trig on acts.

Comment: Did you notice the changed part in the `artist` trigger?

Comment: well i didnt notice MIN(salary) but still the problem is in `acts` `ERROR: Error 1235: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'` maybe i should ignore update trigger in acts and use only instert for example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7274/discussion-between-ypercube-and-geo-papas)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't store all movie participants in one table? Then relationship is straightforward, and you just need to enforce min salary for a particular type of involvement :

```
CREATE TABLE involvement_type
(
  involvement_type_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  description varchar(100)
)
--Instead of acts,directs,writes you will have just one table
CREATE TABLE movie_participant
(
   movie_id,participant_id, involvement_type_id, salary
   -- PK is (movie_id,participant_id, involvement_type_id) assuming 
   -- one person can be involved in different ways, say artist and director       
   -- each of (movie_id,participant_id, involvement_type_id) is FK to appropriate table
)
```

Also, I wouldn't use movie.title as a primary key. Even if you prefer natural pk over surrogate for some good reason, title itself cannot identify the movie (I'm not familiar with movie domain, but I guess title is just a part of unique constraint)

Comment: well i believe its better not to have another table with dublicate data. Lets stay on topic though :)

Comment: I don't see any duplication. If one person is an artist and a director, [s]he has 2 salaries... But if you want to stick with you approach , I don't see any reliable solution except limiting write access to your 3 tables (acts, directs, and writes) to stored procedure that ensures  salary has a proper value.

Comment: and how can i limit access to these tables? by setting a constrain?

Comment: `GRANT`/`REVOKE`. Application[s] accesses database using login which doesn't have write permissions to these tables. Instead of inserting/updating the app calls the procedure which has permissions.

Comment: any chance you could edit your answer or add a trigger code based only on the schema that i have given? ^^